# Shopware 6 - custom entity and custom role with one to many associations. How to get data from a custom repo or autoload the extension

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I created a custom entity with definition, collection, migration, etc. It is called tickets. I also created a customer extension to have a relation `one too many`(One customer can have multiple tickets but the ticket can have only one owner - customer).

```php
$collection->add(              
   (new OneToManyAssociationField(                     
      'ticket',                      
      TicketDefinition::class,                      
      'customer_id',               
   ))               
   ->addFlags(new CascadeDelete())        
);
```

Now I want to create a custom rule and everything goes well but how can I get the data from the custom collection? I can't inject a service into the rule and according to the documentation, I should stick with the data provided by scope.
My question is how can I get those data in the match method?

```php
public function match(RuleScope $scope): bool   {     
   $scope->getSalesChannelContext()->getCustomer()->getExtensions()   
}
```

returns null.

In the command, I can do a similar thing and when I do association with the criteria everything works but in the match method I can not do things like this.

I also checked and in the rest of the associations, there is an option `autoload` but not in `OneToMany`.

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually add the association when the entities are loaded, as `OneToManyAssociationField` does not support auto-loading. If you want to do this globally you can subscribe to `EntitySearchedEvent` and add the association to the criteria. This should make the extension available globally.

```php
class EntitySearchSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            EntitySearchedEvent::class => 'onEntitySearch',
        ];
    }

    public function onEntitySearch(EntitySearchedEvent $event): void
    {
        if ($event->getDefinition()->getEntityName() !== CustomerDefinition::ENTITY_NAME) {
            return;
        }

        $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('ticket');
    }
}
```